# Replace variable in one column differentially based on another variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column in one db that is a variable, with a corresponding index value in another column.  I would like to replace the index variable with a different set of data, but based on the variable in the first column.

```
Col1 Col2 

A    1
A    2
A    3
A    4
B    1
B    2
B    3
B    4
C    1
C    2
C    3
C    4
```

I want to replace the 1 through 4 values with vectors dependent on the Col1 value.

```
If A: replace c(1:4) with c(10, 5, 2, 4)
If B: replace c(1:4) with c(20, 19, 8, 5)
IF C: replace c(1:4) with c(30, 25, 20, 17)
```

This is the code I've used before  to do this in a column without dependency on another, but I can't get it to work with my current situation:

```
col
1
2
3
4

index <- c(1:4)
foo <- c(4,5,6,8)
df$col <-  foo[match(df$col, index)]

col
4
5
6
8
```

Comment: Have a solution: `df$col2[df$col1 %in% "A"] <- c(10,5,2,4)` `df$col2[df$col1 %in% "B"] <- c(20, 19, 8, 5)` `df$col2[df$col1 %in% "C"] <- c(30, 25, 20, 17)`

Answer (score 1):

Trying with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Col1 = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4), rep("C", 4)),
                 Col2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4))

A <- c(10, 5, 2, 4)
B <- c(20, 19, 8, 5)
C <- c(30, 25, 20, 17)

dt[Col1 == "A", Col2 := A]
dt[Col1 == "B", Col2 := B]
dt[Col1 == "C", Col2 := C]

print(dt)
    Col1 Col2
 1:    A   10
 2:    A    5
 3:    A    2
 4:    A    4
 5:    B   20
 6:    B   19
 7:    B    8
 8:    B    5
 9:    C   30
10:    C   25
11:    C   20
12:    C   17
```

In case you need the result as a `data.frame`, you can always switch back efficiently by

```
setDF(dt)
```

without copying.